# How to check the event of change of url in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a script which runs every time a url is changed in tab.Right now I am anle to check the events of downloads,active tabs but not able to ceck the event of change of webpage/url in a tab.How can I do this?Can I do this by using Autoupdating feature of chrome extension.Please Help!!Currently I am using:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(activeInfo){
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#history

You should leverage the HTML5 History API for this one, bro.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?